# SQL Join Query Selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please look at the below tables and result. Check my query and help me to get the result as below.

```
Table : incident
----------------
incident_id   usr_id    item_id
10059926       191       61006

Table: act_reg
--------------
act_reg_id  act_type_id  incident_id    usr_id  act_type_sc
454244         1        10059926         191    ASSIGN
471938        115       10059926         191    TRAVEL TIME
473379        40        10059926         191    FOLLOW UP
477652        115       10059926         191    TRAVEL TIME
477653        107       10059926         191    SITE ARRIVAL
489091      5000054     10059926         191    ADD_ATTCHMNTS

Result(Need to get)
-------------------
incident_id   usr_id    item_id  Attachment
10059926       191      61006     Yes
```

My query:

```
SELECT incident.incident_id,incident.usr_id,incident.item_id,Attachemt
FROM incident RIGHT JOIN act_reg ON incident.incident_id=act_reg.incident_id
```

Comment: Just use a `INNER JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`.  Or even `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff both getting same result

Comment: @Salman from where i get attachment?

Comment: GROUP BY incident.incident_id,incident.usr_id,incident.item_id,Attachemt

Comment: Not sure why did this question get up-votes. I don't even understand what does OP want to ask?

Comment: @ChiragThakar in Act_reg table

Comment: @Salman i think you should try the answer given by Tim Schmelter, according to me thats perfect answer

Comment: @ChiragThakar Yes, Tim Schmelter code is perfect

Comment: @aSharma i need to get only rows from table incident and an additonal column if there are attchments, which is the case if there is at least one record in table act_reg with the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your requirement you want only rows from table `incident` and an additonal column if there are attchments, which is the case if there is at least one record in table `act_reg` with the same `incident_id` + `usr_id` and `act_type_sc=ADD_ATTCHMNTS`.

I would use `CASE WHEN EXISTS`:

```
SELECT incident_id, usr_id, item_id,
       Attachment = CASE WHEN EXISTS
                    (
                       SELECT 1 FROM act_reg a
                       WHERE i.incident_id  =   a.incident_id
                        AND  i.usr_id       =   a.usr_id
                        AND  a.act_type_sc  =  'ADD_ATTCHMNTS'
                    ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM incident i
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/478e7/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: Go for this answer, i guess its proper solution!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help

```
SELECT  incident.incident_id,incident.usr_id,incident.item_id,
        'Yes' Attachemt
  FROM  incident 
  where exists (select * from act_reg 
                  where incident.incident_id = act_reg.incident_id
                    and act_reg.act_type_sc  = 'ADD_ATTCHMNTS'
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what Attachment means but if you want another column for your join result you can use this. The result will contain only the rows that are required

```
SELECT incident.incident_id,incident.usr_id,incident.item_id, 'yes'
FROM incident, act_reg WHERE incident.incident_id = act_reg.incident_id;
```